# Is HTTP body optional?

Tags: http

As you know `204 No Content` has no body ,Can we have no body for other statuses

Specially for

- 202 Accepted
- 201 Created

Comment: https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#message.body

Answer (score -1):

204 No contents means that the server response was returned with no content. Depending on which HTTP verb is used with the request, you might have a body or not. for example, an HTTP GET has no Body while an HTTP POST has a Body. Status codes informs the requesting client about the status code of the request and this is because HTTP is a stateless protocol. to get more information about HTTP Verbs and status codes, I encourage you to visit this sit: [Learn REST: A RESTful Tutorial](https://www.restapitutorial.com/)

Comment: Can you tell me , Can I have no body for `202 Accepted` response?